# Bind a suffix to each item in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to bind a suffix to each item in an array? Thank you in advance.

```
Test.assertSimilar(addEnding(['clever', 'meek', 'hurried', 'nice'], 'ly'), ['cleverly', 'meekly', 'hurriedly', 'nicely'])
```

Comment: Please add the code you've tried

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map()` to get the desired output:

```js
const data = ['clever', 'meek', 'hurried', 'nice'];
const suffix = 'ly';
const result = data.map(v => v + suffix);

console.log(result);
```